# AngularJS angular-animate bug in 1.4.0 vs 1.2.1? Animation behaves differently from one version to the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

Refer to this two examples of an animation using angular-animate, in both cases I am using the exact same code, I only upgrade the angular and angular-animate versions from 1.2 to 1.4, and the whole sliding animation is totally different, I believe it is a bug, do you think so?

It is mandatory to include some code along with the links, so I did, however the code is irrelevant as it is the exact same code for both cases.

EDIT: I am using the latest documentation for this code.

http://jsfiddle.net/a453t3dx/

```
    <div ng-controller="controller">
    <div class="animate-show" ng-click="goToSlide(1)" ng-class="{forward: direction, backward: !direction}" ng-show="stepWizard==1">1</div>
    <div class="animate-show" ng-click="goToSlide(2)" ng-class="{forward: direction, backward: !direction}" ng-show="stepWizard==2">2</div>
    <div class="animate-show" ng-click="goToSlide(3)" ng-class="{forward: direction, backward: !direction}" ng-show="stepWizard==3">3</div>
    <button ng-click="goToSlide(stepWizard-1)">Previous</button>
    <button ng-click="goToSlide(stepWizard+1)">Next</button>    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a453t3dx/3/

```
    <div ng-controller="controller">
    <div class="animate-show" ng-click="goToSlide(1)" ng-class="{forward: direction, backward: !direction}" ng-show="stepWizard==1">1</div>
    <div class="animate-show" ng-click="goToSlide(2)" ng-class="{forward: direction, backward: !direction}" ng-show="stepWizard==2">2</div>
    <div class="animate-show" ng-click="goToSlide(3)" ng-class="{forward: direction, backward: !direction}" ng-show="stepWizard==3">3</div>
    <button ng-click="goToSlide(stepWizard-1)">Previous</button>
    <button ng-click="goToSlide(stepWizard+1)">Next</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: There've been major changes on animation between these two versions, including breaking changes. I would start at looking at the release notes to narrow down what is happening: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I understand, I will have a look, but the code in the older angular version seems to behave correctly as it should, and the one with the 1.4 version it is totally messed up, it would expect it to be the other way round.